# Does Redshift use the same key distribution when two tables have the same distribution keys?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have several tables that contain the field customer_id.

There is not a lot of customer_ids but the underlying data is big (100s Gb per customer id).

All my queries always use this customer_id one way or another: join, aggregate or filter.

Consequently, this field seems to be the best candidate for the distributing  key.

**Question:** If I set the same DISTRIBUTION KEY(customer_id) on all my tables, will redshift know that I want data for a specific customer on the same node for all these tables?
If yes, how does it decide of this? simply by using the column name being similar over all these tables?
This seems weird to me but I couldn't find anything on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift will **hash** the value in the `DISTKEY` column.

For example, if your cluster has a total of 4 slices, it will hash the key and use a modulo of 4. This will result in any value have value of 0-3. It then uses the value to distribute those rows on a specific slice.

If the number of nodes, and therefore slices, changes, then the hash will be recalculated for each row.

Always remember the basic rules:

- Set `DISTKEY` to the column that is most commonly JOINed
- Set `SORTKEY` to the column(s) most commonly used in `WHERE`

Comment: Also be aware of your platform’s behaviour towards different, but similar, data types.  On Teradata, related data types (e.g. byteint, smallint, integer, bigint) will yield the same hash for the same data value.  Redshift may behave differently, which may in turn mean you need to be more prescriptive about your datatyping on distribution key column.

Comment: Thanks John; what I really want to know tough is wether or not the these slices on same keys but from different tables end up on the same nodes. Any input regarding this?

Comment: Yes, a `DISTKEY` column with the same value in the column will always end up on the same slice, for all tables.